# How to cast a 32-bit integer from unsigned to signed in MySQL or PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, casting, unsigned, signed

I have a string in PHP (came from some data source), which represents a formatted unsigned 32-bit integer.
I need to store it into a MySQL database as a *signed* 32-bit integer, so that later I can retrieve it from PHP and use it as a (possibly negative) signed integer constant (since PHP doesn't have unsigned integers).

So, what I need is a conversion method, either for PHP or MySQL. It shouldn't be platform-dependent (no endian / 32/64-bit issues).

I know how to convert a signed integer into unsigned using MySQL:

```
select CAST((-1062726980 & 0xFFFFFFFF) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER);
+------------------------------------------------------+
| CAST((-1062726980 & 0xFFFFFFFF) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) |
+------------------------------------------------------+
|                                           3232240316 | 
+------------------------------------------------------+
```

But I can't get it work the other way around (note: MySQL uses 64-bit arithmetic when doing casts).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
$val = (bccomp("2147483647", $val) < 0) ? bcsub($val, "4294967296") : $val;
```

seems to work, even though it's somewhat slow.

Answer (score 3):

If you just cast the number to an integer in PHP, it will do the trick.

```
echo (int)3232240316 . "\n";
```

gives

```
-1062726980
```

Note: if you want to cast a signed int to an unsigned int in PHP, just do this:

```
$number += 4294967296;
```

Example:

```
$number = -1062726980;
echo $number . "\n";
$number += 4294967296;
echo $number . "\n";
```

gives:

```
-1062726980
3232240316
```

Comment: Sorry, but that won't work on some 64-bit systems, where PHP int is 64-bit by default.

Answer (score 1):

Pure MySQL solution:

```
SELECT CAST((yourUnsigned<<32) AS SIGNED)/(1<<32)
```

gives you 32-bit complement UNSIGNED->SIGNED conversion, when `yourUnsigned` is in the range 0..4294967295. SIGNED->UNSIGNED is easy:

```
SELECT yourSigned & 0xFFFFFFFF;
```